# Cannot access properties of Immutable.js map

Tags: javascript, typescript, immutable.js

I use Immutable.js to deserialize stored maps. Unfortunately I have not yet managed to access properties of the map. If I run the code like below, I get the right map entry. If I try to access the property name, I get an undefined object. I'm new to JS and haven't quite figured out how to access the entries yet.

I get this object back if I run the following code. How can I access the name now?

```
let map: Immutable.Map<string, User> = Immutable.fromJS(users[index].userMap).toMap();
console.log(map.get("4");
```

```
Map {size: 2, _root: ArrayMapNode, __ownerID: undefined, __hash: undefined, __altered: false}
  size: 2
  _root: ArrayMapNode
    ownerID: OwnerID {}
    entries: Array(6)
      0: (2) ["name", "joe"]
      1: (2) ["text", "test"]
      length: 2
      __proto__: Array(0)
  __proto__: Object
  __ownerID: undefined
  __hash: undefined
  __altered: false
  state: true
__proto__: KeyedCollection
```

**User**

```
export interface User {
  name: string;
  text: string;
}
```

```
userMap: Immutable.Map<string, User>;
```

Comment: It looks like the Map only has 2 entries, and `4` is not one of those keys?

Comment: If I run `map.get("4")` I get this object back and with `map.get("4").name` I get undefined.

Comment: Please show what's in `users`

Comment: It's working now with `map.getIn(["4", "name"]);`, but I cannot use `setIn(["4", "name"], "newName")`. it just won't update the name.

Comment: @AluanHaddad users come from the NGXS store state.

Comment: Right, but what's in it? Can you provide an example of the actual data in `users` I don't mean that the type

Answer (score 1):

#### Issues with access

Using typescript tricked you into thinking that that map actually contains `User`. It does not. `Immutable.fromJS` deeply converts objects to maps, unless the objcts are Immutable objects (e.g. Map, List, Record,...).

You even saw it when `console.log(map.get("4"));` returned an `Immutable.Map`.

So to access it, treat them like nested maps: `map.getIn(["4", "name"]);`
Or convert the Users to [Immutable.Records](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record) before adding them to the map:

```
const UserRecord = Record({ name: undefined, text: undefined });
Immutable.Map(users[index].userMap.map(entry => UserRecord(entry));
console.log(map.get("4").name);
```

#### Issues with modification

> It's working now with map.getIn(["4", "name"]);, but I cannot use
>   setIn(["4", "name"], "newName"). it just won't update the name.

You might not have fully understood how immutable works. Immutable objects never change (that's the whole point!). `map.setIn(["4", "name"], "newName")` will not change anything, it returns a new map that contains the updated data! You would have to assign it to something to see the updated data, e.g.

```
const changedMap = map.setIn(["4", "name"], "newName");
```